# Why get request http dont working in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

Hi guys i have problem with getting http request if i write "http://10.0.1.42:8080/state"(this is my ip) on emulator chrome this working, but if i want getting http request aplication close. Can someone help me?

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.util.*

class kmnActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val EXTRA_TEXT = "com.example.application.example.EXTRA_TEXT"
    var uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    var response = "nothing"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kmn)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView3)

        val kamenButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.kamen)
        val papierButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.papier)
        val nozniceButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.noznice)

        kamenButton.setOnClickListener {
            get_state()
            textView.setText(response)
           // openRollActivity()
        }

        papierButton.setOnClickListener {
            openRollActivity()
        }

        nozniceButton.setOnClickListener {
            openRollActivity()
        }
    }

    fun get_state(){
        val client = HttpClient()

        runBlocking {
             response = client.get<String>("http://10.0.1.42:8080/state") //Here not working
        }

        client.close()
    }

    fun openRollActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this@kmnActivity, rollActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("id", uuid)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Or if somebody have better way, He can said me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
Add this code AndroidManifest.xml file
could refer to this https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6 u will get the clear idea over it

another possible fix will be
instead of HTTP can use https